# Some inequalities on chain of circle packing

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, inequalities, plane-geometry, circle-packing

By my computation, I pose a conjecture as follows and I am looking for a proof:

> > **Conjecture:** *Let $(O)$ be a circle with radius $R$, and $n$ be positive integer $n\ge 3$. Construct $n$ circles $(O_1), (O_2), \cdots, (O_n)$ external tangent to $(O)$ and $(O_i)$ tangent to $(O_{i+1})$ for $i=1$, $2$, $\cdots$, $n$ and $(O_{n+1}) \equiv (O_1)$. If radius of $(O_1)$, $(O_2)$, $\cdots$, $(O_n)$ are $r_1$, $r_2$, $\cdots$, $r_n$ respectively then*
> >
> > $$r_1+r_2+\cdots+r_n \ge \frac{n\sin^{\frac{\pi}{n}}}{1-\sin{\frac{\pi}{n}}} R$$

and

> > $$r_1^2+r_2^2+\cdots+r_n^2 \ge n\left( \frac{\sin{\frac{\pi}{n}}}{1-\sin{\frac{\pi}{n}}} \right)^2R^2$$

**See also:**

- [Circle packing in a circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw the tangents $OP_i$ and $OQ_i$ from $O$ to the circle $(O_i)$ and let $\theta_i=\frac{1}{2}\angle P_iOQ_i$. These angles satisfy $\theta_i \in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ and $\theta_1+\cdots+\theta_n\geq\pi$. This is because the sectors $P_iOQ_i$ cover the whole plane. We can express
$$r_i=\frac{R\sin \theta_i}{1-\sin \theta_i}$$
So both your inequalities can be rewritten in the form
$$\frac{f(\theta_1)+\cdots+f(\theta_n)}{n}\geq  f\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right).$$
with $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{1-\sin x}$ and $f(x)=\left(\frac{\sin x}{1-\sin x}\right)^2$ respectively. To prove this we can first establish
$$\frac{f(\theta_1)+\cdots+f(\theta_n)}{n}\geq f\left(\frac{\theta_1+\cdots+\theta_n}{n}\right)$$
since both of these functions are convex in the desired interval so it follows from [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality). And then the inequality
$$f\left(\frac{\theta_1+\cdots+\theta_n}{n}\right)\geq f\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)$$
follows fromthe fact that both functions are increasing in this interval.

Comment: Can You see my comment in figure:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6nFU.png ??

Comment: @ĐàoThanhOai thank you for catching the mistake. It should be fixed now.

Comment: $f(x)=\left(\frac{\sin x}{1-\sin x}\right)^n$ is convex increasing in $(0. \frac{\pi}{2})$ with any $n \ge 1$. How can prove that?